# php suddenly thrown error "The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration. See our documentation for more information."

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I was setting up a site and everything was working fine suddenly my php thrown an error

```
The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration. See our documentation for more information.
```

When i type `php --version` i get response :

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqli.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqli.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20170718/mysqli.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 (cli) (built: Sep 13 2018 13:45:02) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

and for `mysql --version` response is :

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

My ubuntu version is 18.04. What can be gone wrong ? Please help. I didnt do any upgrade or install

and my extensions in php.ini is

```
;extension=bz2
;extension=curl
;extension=fileinfo
;extension=gd2
;extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=interbase
;extension=ldap
;extension=mbstring
;extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
;extension=mysqli.so
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
;extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
;extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop

; The MIBS data available in the PHP distribution must be installed.
; See http://www.php.net/manual/en/snmp.installation.php
;extension=snmp

;extension=soap
;extension=sockets
;extension=sqlite3
;extension=tidy
;extension=xmlrpc
;extension=xsl
```

Comment: Can you share the content of `php.ini` as well?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous thats a huge file right,

Comment: Share the lines that start with `extension=...`

Comment: Most likely your php instalaltion got updated only partially. Or the extension got removed due to failing dependencies.

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous done

Comment: @arkascha - might be it got removed..but how to check ?

Comment: Try removing this `.so`. Leave it just `mysqli`

Comment: @D.Dimitrov - tried still no luck

Comment: ; is a comment. So all the extensions in the php.ini are commented out.
But not sure what happened here. Also this way is deprecated loading extensions. There should be a directory (/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/) for the extensions. Please consult the apache docs in the version your apache is running.

Comment: @kitingChris - but it was woking before. nothing changed

Comment: Which `php.ini` you are editing? Place a file with `phpinfo();` and see `Loaded Configuration File` - is it the one you are editting?

Comment: Please remove the semicolon before extension=mysqli.

Comment: @D.Dimitrov - could you please explain in detail. sorry I am new to php and mysql

Comment: You need to remove semicolon(comment) before the extensions to use them.And then Eval phpinfo(); If you are not able to see the extension enabled restart the apache service.

Comment: @sady I tried but no luck

Comment: How to check? You could go through your apt log files, but I doubt that will really help. Apparently it is _not_ installed (you can check that in your software management). What happens if you try to install it?

Comment: Create new PHP file in your web root, place one line there `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, load it in your browser and look for `Loaded Configuration file`.

Comment: @D.Dimitrov, its loading the same configuration file which I am editing

Answer (score 2):

The error is very self-explanatory. Your system is not configured to have **mysqli** enabled. You have to make sure the extension is installed and enabled correctly.

To install mysqli if it's missing

> sudo apt-get install php-mysql

For Ubuntu I seem to remember your are not advised to edit the php.ini directly but instead use **phpenmod** to enable modules.

Example

> phpenmod mysqli

To check mysqli setting in PHP you can run something like

> php -r 'phpinfo();' | grep -i mysqli

Comment: Remember to accept answers so people know it's been solved for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Install one of the packages that contain your package. Pick the latest:

Also, when installing a package, make sure your libraries are updated with these commands:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt install php7.2-mysql
```

here is some examples for php packages

```
apt-get install php-pear php7.2-curl php7.2-dev php7.2-gd php7.2-mbstring php7.2-zip php7.2-mysql php7.2-xml
```

Comment: so here i need to install mysqli plugin ?

Answer (score 1):

you just need to uncomment  following line
;extension=mysqli.so in php.ini

To uncomment this line just remove initial (;) from the line. save ini file and restart server.
it should work